# Função imagecopyresampled() do PHP cortando no lugar errado

Tags: php

Já inverti varias vezes os parâmetros para verificar se eu estava os passando erroneamente, porém não obtive sucesso. O que está acotecendo é que o crop é realizado num local diferente do especificado. 
Estou utilizando o jQuery e o plugin jCrop para achar as coordenadas. No lado cliente funciona tudo normal.

**Como na imagem abaixo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Selecionei a área que está no print acima e ele recortou num local totalmente diferente:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Inicialização do Jcrop**

```
$('#target').Jcrop({
     onSelect: showCoords,
     onChange: showCoords,
     aspectRatio: 960/720,
     boxWidth: 600,
     boxHeight: 400,
     bgColor: '#674323'
 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0ysv65p/)

**Esse é script PHP onde faço o crop no Server-side:**

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $dst_x = 0;
        $dst_y = 0;
        $src_x = ceil($_POST['x']); // x1 da imagem de origem
        $src_y = ceil($_POST['y']); // y1 da imagem de origem
        $dst_w = ceil($_POST['w']); // largura da imagem de destino
        $dst_h = ceil($_POST['h']); // altura da imagem de destino
        $src_w = ceil($_POST['x2']); // x2 da imagem de origem
        $src_h = ceil($_POST['y2']); // y2 da imagem de origem

        $jpeg_quality = 100;

        $src = 'css/images/luitame.jpg';
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
        $imageName = "css/images/thumbs/".time().'.jpg';
        imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
        imagejpeg($dst_r, $imageName, $jpeg_quality);

        header("location: result.php?img=$imageName");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Confere se os valores da posição de corte estão corretos, ele está assumindo que a posição do corte como 0 x 0.

Comment: @touchmx estou usando '0,0' por que esse é o destino X, Y respectivamente da imagem de destino. Em miúdos essa é coordenada onde será colada a imagem copiada com a função. Ao meu ver esse parâmetro é pra isso. Me corrija se discordar.

Comment: @bfavaretto você pode fazer isso exemplificando com a função? Por favor. Não entendi ao certo o que quis me passar.

Comment: @Luitame já conferiu na documentação do php se os parametros passados estão corretos? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: @touchmx conferi sim, mas não consigo entender com clareza. É nesta parte que estou com dúvida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Acho que meus comentários acima não procediam, o JCrop já lida automaticamente com a escala, segundo a [documentação](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html). Removi os comentários (e logo removo este aviso também).</sup>

---

Eu acho que você está passando as dimensões erradas da área de corte, que são obtidas aqui:

```
$src_w = ceil($_POST['x2']); // x2 da imagem de origem
$src_h = ceil($_POST['y2']); // y2 da imagem de origem
```

Faltou subtrair a posição de origem para, aí sim, ter a altura e a largura. Ou usar a altura e a largura que o JCrop já calculou pra você, trocando os dois últimos parâmetros passados para `$dst_w` e `$dst_h`:

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $dst_w, $dst_h);
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração aqui passada e não mudou muita coisa. Continua cortando no local errado.

Comment: Mas mudou o erro, ou continua errando igual? :) Não sei bem o que está ocorrendo... Entendeu a lógica da minha resposta? As dimensões da imagem gerada serão iguais às dimensões da área definida para crop. Volto a achar que está tendo algum problema de escala.

Comment: Entendi o que quis passar. Mas, ainda ela corta no local errado.

Comment: @Luitame Quando você define a área de corte, o x,y da origem que ele mostra é em relação à imagem escalada ou full size? Por exemplo, se você começa a marcação a uns 10px do canto da imagem, ele diz 10px ou mais que isso?

Comment: E tenta também retirar o `aspectRatio` passado ao JCrop na inicialização (client-side).

Comment: Fiz vários testes e caí lá onde você tinha falado. O problema era uma caquina na tag `IMG` tinha definido um altura fixa de X pixels. O que complicava a escala... Mas deu certo! Retirei a altura e defini através de um metodo do jCrop chamado `boxHeight`. Funcionando... Obrigaaado

Answer (score 2):

Observando o código em `crop.php` nos exemplos do plugin jCrop,  temos o código executado quando o usuário dá um POST:

```
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = 'demo_files/pool.jpg';
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,
//destino x_y           src x_y
0,          0,          $_POST['x'],    $_POST['y'],
//destino w_h           src w_h
$targ_w,     $targ_h,     $_POST['w'],    $_POST['h']);
```

Abaixo temos o exemplo gráfico do que acontece no código do `imagecopyresampled` do código de exemplo: 
 [image: 1]

O que você deve mudar é o `$src_h` e o `$src_w` para os valores `$_POST['h']` e `$_POST['w']` respectivamente.

Comment: Obs.: Parece que `$_POST['x2']` e `$_POST['y2']` são de uso interno (ou para calcular o aspecto) quando `aspectRatio = 0`, é o que estou verificando no momento.